# How to iterate through an array of objects all residing on index 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple quiz app for my assignment using firebase. When I retrieve my questions from firebase I get an array which contain 1 object which contains 2 objects of its own.

Like this: [image]

I want to render them on virtual dom separately like a quiz. Is there a way to iterate through them like using `Questions.Q1.Question` but when user presses the next button it will switch to `Questions.Q2.Question` dynamically for all questions.

I am getting questions like this:

```
getQuestions() {
    const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("Quizes").child("JavaScript").child("Quiz 2").child("Questions");
    firebaseRef.on("value", snap => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            Questions: [...prevState.Questions, snap.val()]
        }))
    })
}
```

Then rendering them:

```
renderQuiz() {
    const { Questions, currentQuestion } = this.state;
    let QTile, choice_1, choice_2, choice_3, choice_4 = "";
    Questions.map(value => {

        QTile = value.Q1.Question;
        choice_1 = value.Q1.Choice_1;
        choice_2 = value.Q1.Choice_2;
        choice_3 = value.Q1.Choice_3;
        choice_4 = value.Q1.Choice_4;
    })
    return (
        <div className="panel-group questions">
            <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">{QTile}</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <input type="radio" value={choice_1} /> {choice_1}
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <input type="radio" value={choice_2} /> {choice_2}
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <input type="radio" value={choice_3} /> {choice_3}
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <input type="radio" value={choice_4} /> {choice_4}
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.nextQuestion} style={{ float: "right", marginTop: "15px" }}>Next</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Next question is empty currently:

```
nextQuestion() {
    console.log("Next Question");
}
```

Comment: That's an array containing one object that contain other objects.

Comment: ... and that makes little sense. Why not having an own object for each question?

Comment: @Jonas Willms Can you tell me how to do that when retrieving data from firebase database. Because using the way I did in getQuestions() I am getting this result

Comment: turn `Questions` into an array

Comment: It is already an array

Comment: Are you sure? To me it looks more like an object into an array... It's just that the array only contains one entry.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) when retrieving your question object. This yields an array with the keys of an object. You store these in a field or your state and an index referring to the current position in this array.

So (sorry, never done Firebase, I'll be checking if I can adapt this to your code), your final state would be:

```
{
    questions: { /* Object of questions, with keys Q1, Q2 and so */ },
    currentQuestionIndex: /* some integer that you would increment */
}
```

Then, to access your questions you would do (in your `render` method):

```
const { questions, currentQuestionIndex } = this.state;
const currentQuestionKey = Object.keys(questions)[currentQuestionIndex];
const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionKey];
```

And to update the question (in your `nextQuestion`):

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, currentQuestionIndex: currentQuestionIndex + 1});
```

**Better solution:**

Another option, would be to turn `Questions` into an array directly using the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) function.